# Iframe doesn't resize! and work responsive

Tags: css, iframe, mobile, responsive

I'm basically trying to embed an iframe into one of my sites. When i put the iframe on the site it doesn't work on mobile - meaning the responsiveness is lost and its not scaling according please [check here](http://www.andonigaldeano.com/apparel/customize)

BUT, when i put the same iframe on a PLAIN HTML file, its completely responsive. [check here](http://ashishtadigiri.com/dirk/)

can you tell me what's wrong here please? I'm thinking some CSS conflict?

Appreciate any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When I go to your website, the `iframe` is not responsive, because the width and height of the iframe are set *inline*. You need to set these (or alter them) *via the CSS* to make it responsive.

That the iframe in the plain HTML file is 'responsive' is because it just shows the whole page, because there's no viewport set. (In your main website, this is the viewport: `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">`). It feels responsive, but is not.

So what you need to do:

1. Remove the inline height and width set on the iframe.
2. Add code to your CSS to make the iframe responsive. See my small example below on how to do this. Play around with it to fit it your needs (and viewports).

```css
.iframe-container {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  padding-bottom: 50%;
  background: lightgrey;
}

.iframe-container iframe {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div class="iframe-container">
     <iframe src="http://spreadshirt.com/"></iframe>
</div>
```

Comment: Hello @Roy thanks for your help, I did try it.. doesn't show up the way i wanted it. its cut off, looks like i need to get the viewport correct. Anyway you can break it down to me? thanks so much for your time

Comment: @musclehustle You need to change the `padding-bottom` to your needs.

Comment: yes thank you i have done that, but what i mean is.. its not fitting in the content completely..like it does in the plain html page. I only see the left part of the iframe as the content doesn't scale.. any ideas? thanks so much for your time again

Comment: @musclehustle Then the content inside the iframe is not built responsive. That is something that's out of your hands.

Comment: hmmm.. then weird how it fits in the working example above, I mean the entire width gets shrunk on iphone easily. Anyways, thanks for trying.. I'm sure there's a solution :)

Comment: @musclehustle Responsive ≠ seeing the whole website. The editor is not built for being responsive.

Answer (score -1):

Just add `#view=FitH` after the pdf URL in your iframe.

Example:

```html
<div class="iframe-container">
  <iframe src="http://example.com#view=FitH"></iframe>
</div>
```

Then use the above CSS as mentioned by Roy. It will fit the pdf as per responsive screen.

Comment: While these links may well be Magento stores, they look very spammy. External links tend to get outdated, so I've removed them. Use example site links only if absolutely necessary.